# Integer solutions to $x^2 + (x-y)^2 = 17^2$, with $x\ge0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

I need help finding integer solutions to $$x^2 + (x-y)^2 = 17^2$$ with $x\ge0$

I know that this is of the form of the pythagorean theorem but I am quite unsure about how to proceed in finding all integer solutions for it.

This question was given to me by my teacher as a challenge question in our precalculus course.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Comment: Make Pythagorean triplet choices:  $ m^2+n^2=x, m^2-n^2=17, 2 m n=x-y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is solved once you find all integer solutions to
$$a^2+b^2=17^2$$
This equation of course admits a solution as $17^2=17\times 17$ and hence the only primes dividing it are of the form $4k+1$ (if this statement doesn't make sense, you should check out [Fermat's Two Square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) or just check that one solution is $(15,8)$).

Once you have one solution, you can find all the solutions using [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4180345/943723).

Comment: thank you for your help. The link was helpful, but once I derive an equation for a line that passes through a known value and some $(x, y)$, what is the next step to finding the solutions? The link doesn't quite provide clarity on this.

Comment: @Jared the link provided has got a few more links. Did you try them (especially the book or the blog post) to see whether things are clearer? Since you have accepted the answer, I guess, it's clear now. If not, please tell me and I'll try editing the answer to provide more details.